# SQL Server 2008 Replication - Fixed Overhead of Replication?

Tags: sql-server-2008, replication

We are using SQL 2008 Transactional replication to replicate data from our production database to our reporting database.

We recently created a new 'Global' database that we would like to have replicated to our various production databases around the world. The number of tables in this database is small (less than 30) and the maximum number of rows in any given table might be a couple thousand. We would not be adding tables and data to this Global database very often.

Our DBA said that the "fixed overhead of replication is disproportional to the amount of data that would be actually replicated". I know a little about transactional replication but not enough to refute this argument. Is there really a great deal of 'fixed overhead' with replication, such that if we're not replicating much data, there is still significant resource usage?

Comment: This is an ideal question for DBA.Stackexchange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- DBA response is very generic. You need to question him further
- If you had enabled replication you can check replication related counters to see the performance (http://www.sqlservergeeks.com/blogs/rahulsharma1975/sql-server-bi/181/replication-monitoring-in-sql-server)
- DBA need to be specific of overhead he is referring (Is it CPU usage / Database size growth ?), How he is calculating what he is arriving at
- What is your subscription method (push or pull ?). pull subscriptions perform much better than push subscriptions in a WAN scenario
- By temporarily Disabling Replication Related SQL Agent Job what is SQL Server performance

Few more good resources

- Determine Transactional Replication workload to help resolve data latency (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/repltalk/archive/2010/10/20/determine-transactional-replication-workload-to-help-resolve-data-latency.aspx)
- SQL Server Replication Explorer (http://replicationexplorer.codeplex.com/)
- Customized Alerts for SQL Server Transactional Replication (http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1901/customized-alerts-for-sql-server-transactional-replication/)